# Angular Material Sidenav Not covering full screen on Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

[image]

On scroll, Sidenav is not taking 100% of the screen and it's also scrolling.

```
<div layout="column">
    <section layout="row" flex>
        <!-- sidenav content -->
        <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left"
                    md-component-id="left"
                    md-whiteframe="20"
                    flex>
            <md-content layout-padding></md-content>
        </md-sidenav>
        <md-content flex layout-padding>
            <!-- page content -->
            <md-content>Page Content</md-content>
        </md-content>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/plunkr solution?

Comment: Make sure the sidenav is `position: fixed` with `height: 100vh`. Also create a fiddle if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place the `md-sidenav` outside of the `div`:

```html
<!-- sidenav content -->
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left"
    md-component-id="left"
    md-whiteframe="20"
    flex>
    <md-content layout-padding></md-content>
</md-sidenav>
<div layout="column">
    <section layout="row" flex>
        <md-content flex layout-padding>
            <!-- page content -->
            <md-content>Page Content</md-content>
        </md-content>
    </section>
</div>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Chan4077/pen/rmJzOL)